# How to know what the e-mail addres is of my Google App admin for my domain?

Tags: google-workspace

We have Google Apps, but nobody seems to know what the e-mail address is to be used as login for the admin console [admin.google.com](http://admin.google.com)

How to know what the e-mail addres is of my Google App admin for my domain?